# Area of a circle inscribed in a rhombus?

Tags: geometry

Let's say we have a rhombus with diagonals $a$ and $b$, which contains an inscribed circle. How can we find the area of that circle in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: You may be able to generalise from this: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.00/jacky4.html

Comment: The wiki page for [rhombus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus) provides the answer, though it doesn't derive it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Obviously, the radius of inscribed circle is also a height $h=OH$ of the right triangle $\triangle AOB$. To find it, use equations for triangle's area
$$
S_{\triangle AOB} = \frac 12 \frac a2 \frac b2 = \frac {ab}8 = \frac 12 ch
$$
where $c = AB$ is a hypotenuse. So $r = h = \frac {ab}{4c} = \frac {ab}{4\sqrt{\frac {a^2}4+\frac {b^2}4}} = \frac {ab}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, and therefore
$$
S_c = \pi r^2 = \frac {\pi a^2 b^2}{4\left (a^2+b^2 \right )}
$$

Comment: A another approach could be remembering the area formula for tangential quadrilateral which in this case would be: $Area = 2r*side$ and you can calculate area and the side in terms of $a$ and $b$.